# What's the practical limit for SQL Connection timeouts using .NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

We are getting ready to promote a new system to production, and are running into issues where the connection to SQL is timing out.

This product was largely written by people who are SQL developers, not familiar with the capabilities of .NET.  What we're finding is that the complexity of the Stored Procedure that's timing out is really high.  Lots of things happening like decision making, control flow, and calling out to 10 other Stored Procs to do calculations.

My gut feeling is that this needs to be refactored into a .NET engine that does the decision making, and then simplified SQL statements to handle data and data quality.  I need help in making that argument.  The SQL Dev has indicated that a 10 minute timeout is appropriate for this system in Production.

.NET has setup a default timeout that is reasonable for most situations...  What's a practical upper limit for setting the SQL Connection timeout?

Comment: I don't see C# being faster for this unless the existing SQL was crappily written.  In which case you just need better SQL developers.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would check that the stored procedure and all the nested procedures are properly optimised before you think about moving code into C#. SQL Profiler, execution plans and statistics are all useful to diagnose this.

If the sql is already optimal you may have to think about how the user interacts with the site for example can the operation be scheduled/queued and the user come back later when it's finished to collect the results.

Re-writing in C# sounds like a lot of work and you'd really need to understand what the sql is doing and how re-writing it is going to help.

Comment: Good call.  I need to run a profiler against it to see how long things are taking.  Do you suggest any tooling other than the built in execution plans?  (Does that still work with nested SP's, etc?)

Comment: The sql server profiler would be the best place to start see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no other options except to increate the timeout, there is no practical limit. I guess you don't have time to rewrite everything in C#. The only problem is see that it will be fragile system, if connection breaks, you must be sure that your database remains in valid state.

Comment: @cHao yeah, right, I meant that vt100 must check that it is done in transactions, I'd better mention that explicitly.

Comment: @cHao but if EVERYTHING is done in one huge transaction that lasts 10+ minutes I expect this app to have serious performance issues.

Comment: Apparently there's *already* serious performance issues.  :)  Maybe that's what's going on, i dunno.

Comment: @cHao it depends on actual amount of work being done, may be for their amounts 10 minutes is reasonable time.

Comment: This is a process called to churn through and calculate data.  It is called by a Windows Service rather than a site, so I'm not worried about UI performance.  It just seems like a job better suited to a tiered application (even if it is SSIS or some other ETL engine), rather than just a single SP call.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe what you are talking about is not SQLConnection timeout but a SQLCommand Time out,
and that can depends on your application.

Its not impractical to have big time out especially if you are executing complex logic,

Comment: You are correct...  I mean the Command Timeout.  What I'm wondering about is what behavior you would expect if holding a connection open for 10 times the default...  Network implications, SQL process implications, etc?

Comment: If you have a lot of these going on you can potentially run out of connections. From web point of view process is going to wait for statement to finish unless you run in asynchronously. Network wise i wouldn't worry to much unless you are moving alot of data. For SQL Server just run that SP simultaneously few dozen times and you will know the impact. I llike SQL Server Profiler for that purpose.